# arcLength function (without OpenCv)

Tags: python, scikit-image, opencv

I'm trying to avoid CV2 for work porpuses. I'm using [skimage.measure.find_contours](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours). But I couldn't find the CV2 [arcLength](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) function equivalent anywhere.

How could I calculate a contour perimeter or a curve length without that CV2 function.

It's my code, just in case:

```
from skimage import measure

hresh = get_threshold(image, 127)
contours = measure.find_contours(thresh, 0.8)

for contour in contours:
    approx = aproximate_curve(contour, 0.1 * my_unknown_arc_length_function(contour))  # I have no idea about arc_length_function implementation
```

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck there too at first, but then I realized it is easy to do the math myself.

Just in case anyone needs this code later.

```py
import numpy as np

def perimeter(contour):
    assert contour.ndim == 2 and contour.shape[1] == 2, contour.shape
 
    shift_contour = np.roll(contour, 1, axis=0)
    dists = np.sqrt(np.power((contour - shift_contour), 2).sum(axis=1))
    return dists.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV the `arcLength()` function is used to find the perimeter of a contour/shape object. It can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

In scikit image the same function can be found in the `measure` module named `perimeter`.

Usage:

```
#--- importing the module ---
from skimage.measure import perimeter

print('Perimeter : {}'.format(perimeter(image)))
```

Make sure the image is of `float` data type. The pixels containing the contour/shape object must be of value `1.0` while the other pixels are of `0.0`.

A lot is discussed about this function [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934156/can-anyone-explain-why-skimage-measure-perimeterimg-returns-this-result)

Comment: Thank you! But, how could apply that function to a single contour instead of all contours in image